# Conversion between WGS84 height and local height datum

Tags: coordinate-system

For x/y or lat/lon or heights between different ellipsoid, we can do conversion by using proj.4. But I found that if I want to convert between WGS84 height and local height, I found that it is not so simple.

For example, I try to convert height of [EPSG:5738](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/5738/) which is Hong Kong Principal Datum from WGS84 height. As it proj.4 file is blank, I cannot do it.

From the official description of HKPD (http://www.geodetic.gov.hk/smo/gsi/Data/pdf/explanatorynotes.pdf), it just shows the rough relationship.

Does it mean I have no luck with doing it in proj.4 or other tools?

Comment: By "local height", do you mean "height above the ellipsoid"?

Comment: This might be of help to you: http://lists.maptools.org/pipermail/proj/2011-August/005844.html

Comment: I don't mean the height above the ellipsoid. It is the local-defined height.

Comment: Thanks for @DevdattaTengshe providing the link, unfortunately, I can't find HKPD gtx file.

Comment: Harold: you want height above a local datum, but you don't have the datum characteristics? So the problem isn't about tools, its about appropriate data?

Comment: @BradHards , you are right!